# How to call a PowerShell file with parameters using VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript, system-tray

Greetings everyone and Happy New Year.

I just learned about PowerShell two days ago and it shows. I am trying to make custom Balloon tips and didn't what to make separate ps1 scripts for every possible event. What I needed was a ps1 with parameters.

I found this bit of code at this site: 
[GitHub Invoke-BalloonTip](https:////github.com/proxb/PowerShell_Scripts/blob/master/Invoke-BalloonTip.ps1)

And I call successfully call it from the PS window with:

```
 . .\Invoke-BalloonTip.ps1
Invoke-BalloonTip -Message 'Message' -Title 'Title' -MessageType Info
```

However, I need to call this from a VBScript. I have tried:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.run("powershell -command . c:\PowerShellTest\Invoke-BalloonTip.ps1" & Invoke-BalloonTip -Message 'Invoked' -Title 'Invoked' -MessageType Info)
```

And

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.run("powershell -command ""& { . c:\PowerShellTest\Invoke-BalloonTip.ps1; Invoke-BalloonTip -Message 'Message' -Title 'Title' MessageType Info }""")
```

And a few others with unsatisfactory results. These two examples are the only ones that show no errors in the PS window when it runs. With these two examples the PS window will show briefly and display no error messages but no Balloon Tip will display.

I am certain it is a syntax issue but I am out of ideas as to what it may be. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Prepend the `-command` arguments with `-noexit` to have the window stay open so you can see any errors it might throw: `"powershell -noexit -command ""..."`

Comment: Thank for that, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the original `Invoke-BalloonTip.ps1` as it tries to use the `System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon` type before it is available (via loading `System.Windows.Forms`).  Adding it earlier in your command should fix things (though it does seem a bit hacky):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.run("powershell.exe -command ""& {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;. C:\PowerShellTest\Invoke-BalloonTip.ps1; Invoke-BalloonTip -Message ""Message"" -Title ""Title"" -MessageType Info}""")
```

`Invoke-BalloonTip.ps1` works straight away in the `PowerShell ISE` as the correct assembly is already loaded by default, but not so in `powershell.exe` or `VSCode`.

Comment: You sir (ma'am?) are a genius! It worked perfectly and I really appreciate the explanation. Now on to the next issue!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone else who comes here with a similar problem, this will not work if there are spaces in your Message or Title. To fix it, I surrounded the strings with single quotes:

```
objShell.run("powershell.exe -command ""& {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;. C:\PowerShellTest\Invoke-BalloonTip.ps1; Invoke-BalloonTip -Message ""'Message with Space'"" -Title ""'Title With Space:'"" -MessageType info}""")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
Dim strTitle, srtContext, strCommang

strTitle = "Title"
srtContext = "Text"

strCommang =    "powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command " & _
                "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms')" & vbNewLine & _
                "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing')" & vbNewLine & _
                "$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon" & vbNewLine & _
                "$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information" & vbNewLine & _
                "$notify.visible = $true" & vbNewLine & _
                "$notify.showballoontip(10,'" & strTitle & "','" & srtContext & "',[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.Run strCommang, 0
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: May want to use vbcrlf instead of vbNewLine.  https://www.promotic.eu/en/pmdoc/ScriptLangs/VBScript/Const.htm